# Как редактировать свойства через Консоль Windows или C#?

Tags: c#, файлы, консоль, свойства

Я взялся за реализацию проекта который будет создавать что-то на подобии водяного знака. Однако естественно что это не должно редактировать сами внутренности **документа**.

Изначально я решил попробовать дописать битовое значение в конец файла, однако это естественно не сработало. Затем я пришел к мета данным, но способа их редактирования я не нашел. Подскажите как мне изменить свойства файла например "Руководителя" [или эти атрибутты](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVnK5.png) без использования дополнительных(платных) библиотек. Отдельное спасибо за приведение примера в виде кода на C# или команды в консоли!

Comment: Общая информация: [Windows Property System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/windows-properties-system). Работа со свойствами DOC-файлов: [тыц](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-retrieve-application-property-values-from-a-word-processing-document). PS: переключить язык документации - в левом нижнем углу.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!